# Error with the shortcut of vb script created by inno setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, shortcut

EDIT: I have made little edit to question, describing cause of problem at last.

I have build a setup using Inno. The main file, from where execution starts, is a vbs file. I have set Inno to make shortcut in desktop with a custom icon. But after installation the shortcut gives vbs error of file missing. If i go to main vbs file and run directly or create another shortcut of that vbs file manually in desktop, I can run that shortcut any number of times. So where is the problem. Is it Inno's problem or some scripting problem.

Here's the vbs script (its aim is to start a batch file but dont show cmd window while opening the batch command)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "run.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I don't know vbs and this script was lying in the Internet. So if there's some obvious problem with the script, please help me correct it.

The exact error I get is:

```
Script: C:\Admin\start.vbs
Line:   2
Char:   1
Error:  The system cannot find the file specified.
Code:   80070002
Source: (null)
```

Here's the script I used in Inno

```
  ; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
  ; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

  [Setup]
  ; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
  ; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
  ; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
  AppName=Test
  AppVersion=1.0
  AppVerName=Test 1.0
  AppPublisher=USV
  DefaultDirName=C:\Test
  DisableDirPage=yes
  DefaultGroupName=Test
  DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
  OutputDir=C:\Users\Ashu\Desktop
  OutputBaseFilename=Test
  SetupIconFile=C:\Test\logo2.ico
  Compression=lzma
  SolidCompression=yes
  ; "ArchitecturesAllowed=x64" specifies that Setup cannot run on
  ; anything but x64.
  ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
  ; "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64" requests that the install be
  ; done in "64-bit mode" on x64, meaning it should use the native
  ; 64-bit Program Files directory and the 64-bit view of the registry.
  ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

  [Languages]
  Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

  [Tasks]
  Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

  [Files]
  Source: "C:\Test\start.vbs"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
  Source: "C:\Test\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
  ; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

  [Icons]
  Name: "{group}\Test"; Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico;
  Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Test}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico;
  Name: "{commondesktop}\Test"; Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico;

  [Run]
  Filename: "{app}\importstarter.bat";
  Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Test}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent
```

EDIT:
I have updated script that closely resembles the problem. Cause for the problem is in shortcut property, target property is set but start in property is set blank. Correcting it to desired directory solves the problem. Program runs in first attempt because setup directly runs from the main file instead of the shortcut. So this must be a problem of Inno Script.

Comment: how is any of this related to VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry, i figured that out. It was by mistake but i didn't know how to remove the tag. Now corrected it.

Comment: For your aim you don't need a VB script at all. It can be done natively in Inno Setup. See the [`ShellExec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) function. To its `ShowCmd` parameter pass `SW_HIDE` to keep the console window opened for the executed batch file hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @TLama I will try your solution. I am new to Inno, so in first attempt, I tried wizard option, except for iconfilename and architecturesallowed. Where should I add this function?

Comment: It depends. Currently you are executing those batch files after the setup successfully finishes the installation process. Although, you're getting those files from a directory containing word *"prerequisite"*, which sounds that you want to run it before the installation. I would need to know the real aim to suggest. Also, the same you can achieve even from the `[Run]` section if you specify `shellexec` and `runhidden` flags. But for sure I can tell you that you can throw away that VBS.

Comment: The whole scenario is after the installation completes, when i want to start the application. Currently, i want to run jar file from x64 java. Before this, I must turn mysql service on and after java application closes, the same sql service should be turned off. Turning services are predefined in a batch file, as a part of miniserver. So I created another batch file (run.bat) which calls start_mysql batch file then opens java and then stop_mysql when java application closes. But I dont want cmd to show, so I pick up this vb script from internet and used this script as starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by a lack of specific working/current paths and the use of relative paths.

When the `vbs` file is run, the working/current directory would be that of the installer, `c:\Windows\`, `j:\MyData\`, etc. When it tries to run `run.bat`, it can't find it in the current directory, resulting in the "The system cannot find the file specified." error from the script engine.

The best way to fix this is to force the current directory of the running script to the folder containing it.
(I don't know how to do this off hand)

Alternatively, you can set the current directory on the shortcuts and the `[Run]` entry:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Test"; Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico; WorkingDir: "{app}";
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Test}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico;
Name: "{commondesktop}\Test"; Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: {app}\logo2.ico; WorkingDir: "{app}";

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\importstarter.bat"; WorkingDir: "{app}";
Filename: "{app}\start.vbs"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Test}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent
```

You can also put this at the top of the batch files so they don't need a specific current directory:

```
cd /d %~dp0
```

Note that recent ([since 2010](http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm#5.3.11)) versions of Inno Setup force a working directory to be set to protect against this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify full path and lose the last pointless line.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "c:\somefolder\run.bat" & Chr(34), 0
```

Comment: Actually folder name is not constant. This script file is placed along side batch file inside a folder, whose name can change depending on situation whether same folder already exist or user changes its directory of installation. But the fact is the script itself runs, only shortcut doesn't run which is created by Inno. Infact, that also works in first attempt.

Comment: If you don't want to specifie the path you'll need to set up experiments monitoring current directory changes by your programs, map out all possible behaviour, and write case specific code.

Comment: That actually helped. thanx, atleast now I know where the problem lies... I have made edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your concern. The issue was with Inno Setup. I updated it to newer version and the problem was gone without making any changes to the script.
The problem was caused since the shortcut does not contain any starting point folder (thanks @Noodles). So it was unable to find file in the default directory of cmd.

Comment: I wouldn't personally call it a problem (as long as you're not able to post a complete script by which could everyone reproduce the issue). I'm fairly sure you'd be able to do what you want without using batch scripts nor VBS.

Comment: It wasn't an Inno issue. Inno just made a change to fix the common developer error of expecting the working path to be set. You should still add a `WorkingDir` parameter to the `[Icon]` and `[Run]` entries, or switch to the script directory on startup (which also allows it to run in other situations: `cd /d %~dp0`.

Comment: Thankyou @Deanna for your valuable answer. I will take note of this in all my future builds.